# Degree of Parallelism in Parallel Hint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

What are the factors to decide the Dop in Parallel hint in Oracle.

eg.

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(employees 3) */ e.last_name, d.department_name
FROM   employees e, departments d
WHERE  e.department_id=d.department_id;
```

How to decide 3 is the correct DOP?

Comment: Why use a parallel hint in the first place, rather than let the database manage it for you under the hood?

Comment: @GMB Oracle doesn't manage parallelism, it has to be specifically enabled. (I guess you could set the PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY to AUTO, and let Oracle pick, but I don't think hardly anybody does that option since parallelism needs to be used carefully.)

Comment: @SI1234 Can you add some more details to your question? Are you trying to maximize a single query and don't care about the rest of the system, or are you trying to find a harmonious balance for the entire system? Also, can you briefly describe your database environment? Your sample query is probably a bad choice for parallelism - small tables like EMPLOYEES and DEPARTMENTS often aren't big enough for the parallelism benefit to outweigh the costs. Parallelism is usually for large data warehouse operations.

Comment: @JonHeller The query imentioned is a sample query. I am trying to understand the concept of Parallel Hint and how to decide DOP in Parallel hint if we use it Datawarehouse applications.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the system I maintain are neither OTLP now Datawarehouse, But something in between. So sometimes it is necessary to use parallelism but you do not want to use *all* resources (all CPU cores) for a single report. Theoretically you can limit DOP by profiles, but resource limiting  is problematic component in Oracle. Also Adaptive DOP in Oracle by default decides by number of free CPU resources, so such a query usually has huge number of parallel workers, which totally kills disk IO.

Oracle session worker processes are single-threaded, neither of them will utilize more than single CPU core. So DOP should always correspond to number of CPU cores and whether it is CPU bound.